# Select count of two columns while grouped by

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select the amount of times a player has won and lost in the following table for each player name that exists in the table.

This table holds games played.

```
┌──┬────────┬────────┐
│id│winner  │loser   │
├──┼────────┼────────┤
│1 │player1 │ player2│
├──┼────────┼────────┤
│2 │player1 │ player2│
├──┼────────┼────────┤
│3 │player2 │ player1│
├──┼────────┼────────┤
│4 │player3 │ player2│
└──┴────────┴────────┘
```

Example: In the above table, player1 would have two wins and one loss. I'm trying to select the amount of wins and losses each player has.

I currently have the following SQL

```
SELECT winner, count(winner) FROM multiplayergamestbl GROUP BY winner
```

This will return each player along with their wins, but the count of losses is not what I'm expecting, count of losses will return the same value as the count of wins. I'm clearly a bit new to SQL, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to do two separate queries (one for winner count and one for loser count) and union them together and use the result as a derived table, like this:

```
select player, max(count_winner), max(count_loser) 
from (

  SELECT winner as player, count(winner) as count_winner, null as count_loser 
  FROM multiplayergamestbl 
  GROUP BY winner

  union all

  SELECT loser as player, null as count_winner, count(loser) as count_loser
  FROM multiplayergamestbl 
  GROUP BY loser

  ) t
group by player;
```

The outer query uses the max aggregate function to flatten the rows, without it you would get five rows instead of three (see [this example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c720f0/4)).

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c720f0/3)

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you for the extra clarification and SQL fiddle as well.

Answer (score 1):

First turn your table into more like the format it should be in using a subquery, then do a simple sum over that:

```
select player, sum(won) won, sum(lost) lost from (
  select winner player, 1 won, 0 lost from multiplayergamestbl
  union select loser, 0, 1 from multiplayergamestbl) x
group by player
```

Answer (score 0):

This might resemble what you want.

```
select 'winner' category
, winner
, count(*) records
from multiplayergamestbl 
group by 'winner', winner

union

select 'loser' category
, loser
, count(*) records
from multiplayergamestbl
```